# How to map Json (from procedure) to Java object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, modelmapper

I have the following SP (SQL server) that return a Json output.

```
BEGIN
SET @jsonOutput = (
SELECT 
    Program.Name AS ProgramName,
    ProgramOwner.FirstName AS OwnerFirstName,
FROM ProgramOwner, Program
WHERE Program.Id = ProgramOwner.ProgramOwner2Program
FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
```

I would like to map the return Json output to a List of ProgramDto via modelMapper. Not sure hot to do that since the return values from call.execute is an Object.

Something like this:

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new 
SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName(programProc).declareParameters(
    new SqlOutParameter("jsonOutput",  Types.VARCHAR));
    Map<String,Object>out = call.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource());
if(out.size()>0) {
    // Only to show what I am trying to do 
    Type rootType = new TypeToken<List<ProgramDto>>() {}.getType();
    modelMapper.map(out.get("jsonOutput"),rootType );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you are trying to get a list of object from 
You can use [Jackson api](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/)

Like this

say for example your json is in variable named jsonData, then you can get the object you need like below.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Type> myList = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(jsonData, Type[].class));
```

You can also find more examples [here](https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-convert-json-array-string-to-list/)